# How to use Aggregator with a Row input in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```scala
val testAgg = new Aggregator[Row, Int, Int] {
  def zero = 0
  def reduce(buffer: Int, row: Row):Int = buffer + 1
  def merge(b1: Int, b2: Int):Int = b1 + b2
  def finish(b: Int): Int = b
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
}
```

I know how to use this aggregator in `DataFrame`, but how to use it in SQL?

```scala
spark.udf.register("testAgg", functions.udaf(testAgg))
spark.sql("SELECT testAgg(*) from mytable2").show() // not work
spark.sql("SELECT testAgg(struct(*)) from mytable2").show() // not work either
```

> `Error: No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "public org.apache.spark.sql.Row org.apache.spark.sql.Row$.apply(scala.collection.Seq)"`

So is it possible to use an Aggregator with Row as input in SQL?